# Mac starts up as administrator

Tags: startup

I just got a new Mac Air for my wife. Every time she starts it up (after installing software, crashes, whatever), it starts up logged in as administrator. This confuses my wife no end (where did all my stuff go?)

How can I make it just go to the login screen?

Comment: A good question to ask is WHY is it doing that? Directly from Apple it won't do that. Has it been repaired or was it purchased used? A machine that was supposed to be new that does that would set off warnings to me.

Comment: It is fresh out of the shrink wrap from the apple store. My best guess is that a software update went bad... It set some flag so that it could reboot into admin but then failed to reset the flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable automiatic login by going into System Preferences, Accounts, then selecting "Login Options" and changing "Automatic login" to "Off":

[image]

Comment: or change it to automatically login as your wife, which'd be even easier.